# "with a fist" or "with the fist"?

Tags: articles

Tell me please which article I need to use in the following sentence.

> John's boss menaced him with **a**/**the** fist saying that if he don't finish the project by evening he will fire him.

I am not sure which article I need to use because the boss has two fists.

Comment: The boss can have two hands but only one fist – like [this guy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wR9.png)

Comment: Something else occurred to me: do you mean that the boss is making fists with both hands?  In that case you would say **fists** and not *a* or *the* fist.

Comment: For what it's worth: *If he* ***didn't*** *finish the project . . .he* ***would*** *fire him.*

Comment: And then John gave his boss **the** finger.

Comment: We have answered this question in many forms before and I believe for you,too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one that sounds fluent is **a** fist, because it happens to be one fist but it is not important or known exactly which one, and it doesn't make a difference.  The fact that the boss has two fists doesn't matter.

"**The** fist" sounds like it's referring to some specific fist that we've already mentioned.

Reference: http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/articles.html
This is just rule #1: *Use the indefinite article a or an only with a singular count noun whose specific identity is not known to the reader.*
It's one fist, but the specific identity isn't known.

Comment: Exactly. Compare: _John's boss gave him **a** banana after work._ It doesn't matter if there is one banana, or a whole bunch.

Comment: You're assuming there has been no previous reference to a fist. If there *has* been (*John closed his fingers into a fist*), then *the* fist (or *this* fist) is completely appropriate—and more warranted than *a* fist.

Comment: @JasonBassford True, but in what we were given, there wasn't.

Comment: Dontcha think this is a duplicate? I don't mind at all myself. Duplicates are ok by me. I was not looking to give you **a** piece of my mind.